# JPA/hibernate inheritance and runtime type of an entity that subclasses an abstract super class/entity

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, entity, runtime-type

I would need some clarification about JPA/Hibernate inheritance.

Say I have an abstract `Fruit` entity that is subclassed by two `Apple` and `Orange` entities. Furthermore, I have an instance of `Orange` in database.

**Can I retrieve this instance from database as a plain `Fruit` and cast it to `Orange`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do:

```
Fruit fruit = dao.get(id, Fruit.class)
if(fruit instanceof Orange)
{
   (Orange) fruit
}
```

and in runtime will be the appropriate type. But if you write a `HQL` you can check for its runtime type. This is usually unneeded if you are done your inheritance and mapping well.

```
select f from Fruit f where f.class = 'a.b.c.Fruit'
```

Answer (score 0):

select f from Fruit f where treat(f as Orange).somePropetyInOrange=:value